# Remove outliers from a noisy curve

Tags: image-preprocessing

Allow me to present some images so that I may explain my problem. The images on the left contain a smooth curve surrounded by lots of outliers/noise. The image on the right depict the desired curve.

[image]

Is there any approach that would help in eliminating the noise and retrieving the original curve. Please note, this can be any smooth curve (the image on the right) and equation is not known. No prior knowledge of the curve equation is available.

Please note that I had originally published this question on Match stackexchange. Posting to data science based on feedback.

Thanks,

Sau

Comment: the method is called regression (eg linear, non-linear and so on..)

Comment: Not sure but as far as I can see the points which follow the pattern are more likely than outliers to have close neighbors, so maybe a method based on estimating the density would help. Another idea which crossed my mind is whether any kind Monte Carlo method could deal with that, maybe by resampling many times the pattern would be emphasized?

Comment: @NikosM. I guess we need something more tricky here, simple regression will not work for case 2 where we have „one to many” situation, i.e. for some x the vertical line will cross f(x) more than once. Any ideas?

Comment: @Erwan  A sampling approach is what I have in mind. Look for small line segments on a patch by patch basis and then try to stitch them back..

Comment: @aivanov, see my updated answer

Comment: @NikosM. The curve in the second figure cannot be represented by a function in Cartesian coordinate system, because there are several Ys that correspond to single X. See the right half of the cleaned picture.

Comment: @NikosM - Yes. This is not a time series data which progresses in one direction.  Could have been a curve which looks like a horizontal parabola of the form `y=ax**2 + bx+c` . Could be a sine curve which along the Y axis.  But, what matters the most is - all the curves are smooth and easily distinguishable from the surrounding noise to the human eye.

Comment: @aivanov, one can model the curve by an implicit-form function instead of explicit one. In any case as my answer suggests one should have reasonable expectations in such an ill-posed problem

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this problem as basically trying to find dense areas inside a cloud with noise.

This is not the only possible solution but you could use a clustering algorithm, and specifically one that tries to find dense areas such as DBSCAN.

I'm going to reproduce the first example and you can go further with the other ones.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

x = np.arange(0,1,.01)
y = np.sin(x)
noisex = np.random.uniform(size = 25)
noisey = np.random.uniform(size = 25)

X = np.hstack([x,noisex])
Y = np.hstack([y,noisey])
D = np.vstack([X,Y]).T

plt.scatter(X,Y);
```

[image]

```
# instantiate your model
plt.scatter(D[:,0],D[:,1], c = dbs.labels_, cmap = "RdYlBu")
plt.colorbar()
plt.title(f"Data with noise in red color");
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment:

1. One can use a regression method (eg linear, non-linear, symbolic, ..) to try to fit a curve to the data.
2. Outliers can be removed in 1 or 2 steps:

   2.a. Remove some points before applying regression, eg by testing how much away they are wrt to std.

   2.b. Remove outliers after fitting the curve and measuring distance of point from curve and discard if above a certain threshold.

[UPDATE]

In curve fitting using regression, one rarely has knowledge of the actual curve, instead one assumes the curve belongs to some class of functions and tries various options.

Furthermore, there are what are called [**symbolic regression** methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression), which assume even less about the actual curve and can even find functions in implicit form, although more tedious.

Finally, some pre-processing to remove outliers before applying regression (eg discard points very "far", density-based approaches, ..) can certainly improve the outcome based on reasonable domain-based assumptions.

The above will work for most of the cases presented in question. This is an [**ill-posed inverse problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem), so one should make some assumptions and have reasonable expectations.

[UPDATE 2]

If your data is only 2D image data and you simply need to get the curve **as an image** (and not need to infer any analytical form of the curve), then doing a combination of blur/lowpass filtering and [edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), can be an option. OpenCV, for example, has [methods](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) to achieve that.

References:

1. [An edge detection based noise removal algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0045790613002188)

> We present an image denoising method using the edge map of an image.
> The denoised image is considered as a linear combination of the
> observed image and its average value, where the coefficients are
> controlled by a local edge detector. The parameters are set on
> suitable values related to noise energy computed by the curvature norm
> of the original image. Implementation can be done in a single
> iteration and the speed of the process is reasonably high. Noise
> reduction quality of the introduced method is compared with Wiener and
> Total Variation based filters for some images. The method appears to
> be easy, fast and useful for very noisy images. The differences
> between our method and the patent 6229578 “Edge Detection Based Noise
> Removal Algorithm” are explained.

2. [How to remove the noise without destroying the main edge?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20088/how-to-remove-the-noise-without-destroying-the-main-edge)
3. [Canny Edge Image - Noise removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194870/canny-edge-image-noise-removal)

Comment: M I have no prior knowledge of the model which fits the points. Just one smooth continuous curve. Could be sine , cubic, etc. Does that make sense or do you want me to elaborate further?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: in case you only need the curve as an image (which is a different problem), see my 2nd update